# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/core/module/descriptor/DependencyDescriptor

Tags: java, maven, groovy

I have a Maven Spring Boot project and I am running the below groovy script in my local(IntelliJ IDE) and getting the error as follows.

**Script**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
@Grab(group = 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module = 'http-builder', version = '0.7.1')
import java.time.LocalDate

GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell()

LOG = new File("C:\\Users\\nsinha10\\Desktop\\MLRE Services\\test\\mlre_payment_feedback_${LocalDate.now()}.log")
LOG << "Starting the process" + "\n"
```

**Error log:**

```
Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/core/module/descriptor/DependencyDescriptor
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/core/module/descriptor/DependencyDescriptor
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ivy.core.module.descriptor.DependencyDescriptor
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc."
```

This happens only when I add @Grab to my script. Normal scripts runs fine. Also I have the maven dependency of groovy-all added to my project.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are running the script from a Spring Boot Java code using `GroovyShell` or another way described [here](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/guide-integrating.html).

If so, you need add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ivy</groupId>
    <artifactId>ivy</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

`@Grab` uses Apache Ivy "under the hood". If you run the script in a more conventional way, you will be informed explicitly in console:

```
Cannot @Grab without Ivy, please add it to your module dependencies
```

However, if you run the script from Java, you can get the same error as you did.
I think this is a serious lack of Groovy documentation, as your question is quite common.